# Saving results of regular expression to csv or xls

Tags: python

I have a log record like this (millions of rows):

```
previous_status>SERVICE</previous_status><reason>1</>device_id>SENSORS</device_id><DEVICE>ISCS</device_type><status>OK
```

I would like to to extract all the words in capital into individual columns in excel using python to look like this :

```
SERVICE SENSORS DEVICE
```

Comment: Where do`SENSORS` and `DEVICE` come from?

Comment: Ah, I see, after formatting correctly

Comment: Are you sure this isn't meant to be xml? It looks malformed. `SERVICE` and `SENSORS` are element contents, whereas `DEVICE` is a tag. What happens to `ISCS` and `OK`? They are in capitals, should they be included? If not how do we know to ignore them?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments from @peter-wood, it isn't clear what your input is. However, assuming that your input is as you posted, then here is a minimal solution that works off the given structure. If it is not quite right, you should be able to easily change it to search on whatever is really your structure.

```
import csv

# You need to change this path. 
lines = [row.strip() for row in open('/path/to/log.txt').readlines()]
# You need to change this path to where you want to write the file.
with open('/path/to/write/to/mydata.csv', 'w') as fh:
    # If you want a different delimiter, like tabs '\t', change it here.
    writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter=',')
    for l in lines:
        # You can cut and paste the tokens that start and stop the pieces you are looking for here.
        service = l[l.find('previous_status>')+len('previous_status>'):l.find('</previous_status')]
        sensor = l[l.find('device_id>')+len('device_id>'):l.find('</device_id>')]
        device = l[l.find('<DEVICE>')+len('<DEVICE>'):l.find('</device_type>')]
        writer.writerow([service, sensor, device])
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn And Peter. Thanks for answering my first question on this forum.this is very helpful. i have been thrown into the deep end on this. I have never worked on log data.and my python is limited to the use of libraries.Shawn is there any resource you could suggest to help me learn more on regular expressions on xml?

Comment: To parse xml you can go with the favorites in the python world of BeautifulSoup or lxml. But you should be able to get an immediate result with the code provided. Did it work for you? If so, please accept and close it out. Good luck!